# Prometheus Listener for JMeter distributed test

Tags: jmeter, prometheus, jmeter-plugins

I was able to configure Prometheus with JMeter but only locally.

I'm trying to connect Prometheus with multiple instances ( agents ) to pull the metrics from.

i've disabled ssl for JMeter and im able to run normally but i cant pull data from the servers.

this is my configuration file
[this is my configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuGoj.png)

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). [Edit] your question and replace image with [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with your configuration file, I don't think Prometheus can scrape anything meaningful from [JMeter Server RMI port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

Also I fail to see why would you have several Prometheus instances, you don't have to install Prometheus on each and every slave

I would rather install Prometheus on a single machine and point JMeter to this machine using `prometheus.ip` and `prometheus.port` [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: im not, that exactly what im trying to do.... i need Prometheus to get the data from those 4 nodes and so far this is failing... how do i point jmeter nodes to send the data to the main machine that contains Prometheus so it can read it and display it in grafana